# Using addAll() on List<? extends E> a and b doesn't work

Tags: java, generics, collections

Why doesn't this *compile*?

```
List<? extends Number> a = new ArrayList<>();
List<? extends Number> b = new ArrayList<>();
a.addAll(b);
```

Comment: Why do you think it *should* work? (Shouldn't it be an error to add `Long`s to an `ArrayList<Integer>`?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it wouldn't be safe.

`List<? extends Number>` should be read as *some list where the element type extends `Number`*. So in runtime `a` could be a `List<Long>` and `b` could be a `List<BigInteger>`. In that case, `a.addAll(b)` would mean "add all BigIntegers to the list of Longs" which, if allowed, obviously wouldn't be type safe.

Comment: Well that is the idea by using `List<? extends Number>` I could do something like that since they extend `Number`.

Comment: `List<? extends Number>` should be interpreted as *some list where the element type extends `Number`*. I think you're after a plain `List<Number>`.

Answer (score 1):

https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html

What really worked for me was Guava:

```
com.google.common.collect.Iterables.concat(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

`List<? extends Number>` means

> Items in this List have all the same class. Not only do they extend
>   Number, but are all the same type.

Due to type erasure during compile, the byte code interpreter does not know (and cannot infer), whether the `?` of a and the `?` refer to the same class.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in my question... have a look again

Comment: @helt, an `List<? extends Number>` can be for instance a `List<Number>` which can contain `Numbers` of different types.

Comment: @aioobe, okay, true. But in the other cases (!= Number), its correct, isnt it?

Comment: No, a `List<MyNumber>` can contain objects of different types (as long as they are all subtypes of `MyNumber`.